# What's the required tensile strength for a wire?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, string

I want to horizontally stretch a 50 meters wire rope and slide 100 kg object from side to side. What should be the minimum tensile strength (or carrying capacity) of the rope to be able to hold the object while it is placed in the middle of the 50 meters? We can assume the rope's weight is 100 grams/meter.

I am sure there's some straightforward formula for calculate this just need some help figuring it out. :)

Comment: Draw a force diagram (this is Physics 101 stuff) - the required tensile strength required depends strongly on how much sag you allow in your wire rope at the center...

Comment: See related answer http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/131444/392

Comment: Another related answer http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/78914/392

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually to get an exact expression for a hanging wire *with a lumped mass* somewhere in the middle is extremely hard (maybe impossible). Another thing to consider is the allowable sag of the rope. If the rope can sag *a lot* then the tension can be low, whereas if low sag is required the tension has to be really high. In addition as the tension increases the rope stretches increasing the sag but relieving the tension. It is a rather complex problem overall,

I can provide an approximate expression when the lumped weight $W$ is located in the middle of the span $S$. Also important is the unit *weight* $w = \frac{m g}{\ell}$. I also consider the rope to be inflexible.

The tension is split into the horizontal tension component $H$ which is constant thought the rope, and the total tangential tension $T$ which increases the further away you go from the sag point. The total sag amount is $D$ and the relationships between $H$, $D$ are $T$ are:

$$ \begin{align}
  T & = H \cosh\left( \frac{w S}{2 H} \right) + \frac{W}{2} \sinh\left( \frac{w S}{2 H} \right) \\
  D & = \frac{H}{w} \left( \cosh \left( \frac{w S}{2 H} \right) -1 \right) + \frac{W}{2 w} \sinh \left( \frac{w S}{2 H} \right)
\end{align} $$

A further approximation of the above can be down when $ H \gg \frac{w S}{2}$

$$ \begin{align}
T & = \frac{8 H^2+w^2 S^2+2 S W w}{8 H} \\
D & = \frac{ \frac{w S^2}{8} + \frac{S W}{4}}{H}
\end{align} $$

Or by solving the last one for the horizontal tension $H$

$$ T = w D + \frac{S}{4 D} \left(W - \frac{w S}{2} \right) $$

In your case $S=50$, $w = 0.1\times9.81$, $W=100\times 9.81$, so for $D=3$ meter sag, the tension is $T=3988$ newtons for example.

Your approximate design expression is $$\require{cancel} T = \frac{11,955}{D} + \left(\cancel{ 0.981 D }\right)$$

**Edit 1**

Upon further examination it can be said that worst tension occurs when the weight is at one end. There you add the vertical tension and the weight and vectorially combine the horizontal tension for the worst tension

$$ T = \sqrt{ (V+W)^2 + H^2 } $$

The vertical tension at the end of a cable is

$$ V = H \sinh \left(\frac{w S}{2 H} \right) $$

The horizontal tension is found (numerically) from the measured sag (without the weight).

$$ D = \frac{H}{w} \left( \cosh \left( \frac{w S}{2 H} \right) -1 \right) $$

**Example**

You string the rope with $D=1$ meter sag. From the above equation you find the horizontal tension to be $H=306.7$ newtons. You can use Wolfram Alpha, Excel or any numeric solver you can find for this step.

$$ 1 = \frac{H}{0.1 \times 8.81} \left( \cosh \left(\frac{0.1\times 9.81 \times 50}{2 H}\right) -1 \right) $$

The vertical tension on one end is then

$$ V = 306.7 \sinh \left(\frac{0.1\times 9.81 \times 50}{2\times 306.7}\right) = 24.55 $$

With a weight of $W = 100 \times 9.81 = 981$ the total tension on the end is

$$ T = \sqrt{(24.55+981)^2 + 306.7^2} = 1051.3 $$

Comment: Whoa... that's some answer! Obviously there's no a straightforward formula. :) Thanks for taking the time. I'm having trouble understanding what exactly is the horizontal tension component H. You said it is constant through the rope, but how do you measure it?

Comment: See edit now for a working example.

Comment: I think I reversed the sense of $W$ in the first equations (you know positive force acting upwards). I will edit and change the sign to reflect the point that $W$ points downwards.